# Как при парсинге на php сохранять каждую итерацию цикла в файл и делать небольшую паузу?

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, который по api получает информацию, когда информации мало, все хорошо отрабатывает. Но, когда объем большой, скрипт зависает из за нехватки времени .... Поэтому нужно как то разделить работу скрипта, сохранив каждую итерацию в файл и наверное сделать небольшую паузу, или как то прервать скрипт и запустить его. Не знаю как правильно сделать, небольшой опыт в данной теме...( Буду признателен помощи

```
    public function getM(){
    $scandir = scandir("../components/id/", 1);
    $id = $this->getId($scandir[0]);
    $connect = curlParser::app()
            ->set(CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->referrer)
            ->set(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->header);

    $res = [];
    foreach($id as $data){
        $res[] = $connect->request("https://сайт/$data");
    }
    return $res;
}

public function getId($scandir){
    $lines = file("../components/id/$scandir");
    return array_map(function($line){
        $log = json_decode(rtrim($line), true);
        return $log;
    }, $lines);

}
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример кода, который отрабатывает у вас долго, что бы можно было понять, каким именно образом нужно переделать для приемлемого времени работы.

Comment: Добавил, извиняюсь

Answer (score 0):

Без кода и ошибки тяжело что-то предположить, но тем не менее:

1. Попробуйте оптимизировать ваш скрипт, возможно где-то память утекает;
2. Отправляйте запросы пачками (array_chunk);
3. Установите время выполнения скрипта (set_time_limit), возможно отваливается именно поэтому;

P.S. а вообще возьмите за привычку прикреплять к вопросу, как минимум, фрагмент кода и ошибку, если такая имеется. В разы ускорит решение вашей же проблемы.

Comment: Отредактировал, добавил код.

Comment: к сожалению ни одна функция не поможет разделить скрипт и сделать паузу между итерациями цикла(

Comment: Как пауза между итерациями поможет?? Время работы скрипта только увеличится. Как уже писали - поставьте неограниченное время выполнения: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов откуда мне было знать, что там за код?! Может в апихе лимит стоит на кол-во запросов и валится именно поэтому.

Comment: @ВинсентэПуххини ваша проблема звучала как *скрипт зависает из за нехватки времени*. Если там где-то стоит лимит - ну проверяйте ответ сервера на каждой итерации и останавливайте цикл или добавьте паузу перед следующим запросом: `sleep(5)`

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов 
1) я не автор вопроса, это не моя проблема
2) вообще изначально проблема звучала как "скрипт зависает". Кликаете на "изменен n часов назад" и увидите историю.

Comment: Зависает он как раз из за большого количества информации. В $res находится огромный многомерный массив. В $data id которые нужны для подключения к сайту. Если id не так много, то парсится нормально.

Comment: А по поводу времени. Может конечно вы правы, что увеличится время. Тогда надо как то прерывать скрипт, сохранять информацию в файл, потом запускать его с того места, где остановился он. Но как сделать это, я что то не могу понять......